# Calling Oracle stored procedure using hibernate in xml

Tags: java, database, hibernate, stored-procedures, orm

I'm trying to modify a Hibernate app to include a new select from a stored procedure in Oracle. I've done Oracle stored procedures returning result sets before so I know what needs to be done there but I'm not very familiar with Hibernate and I am struggling to figure out how to do it similarly to how they have done other calls.

Yes I have seen several Stack Overflow threads on this topic, but they appear to be using all annotations, and this app doesn't use annotations for this section so I want to keep it as close to existing code as possible - they are reports so not even represented by actual tables or entities.

Here's where I am at now:

the result set class:

```
public class Person {

    private Long personId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // constructors omitted
    // getters & setters for properties omitted
}
```

The DAO:

```
public List<Person> getPeopleInDept (Integer deptId) {
    return entityManager.createNamedQuery("getPeopleInDept", Person.class)
        .setParameter("deptId", deptId)
        .getResultList();
}
```

The XML:

```
<named-native-query name="getPeopleInDept" result-set-mapping="PersonMapping">
<query>
{ ? = call GET_PEOPLE_IN_DEPT (:deptId) }
</query>
</named-native-query>

<sql-result-set-mapping name="PersonMapping">
    <constructor-result target-class="package.Person">
       <column name="PERSON_ID" class="java.lang.Long"/>
       <column name="FIRST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
       <column name="LAST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

That's all there is, no annotations which I am not showing here.

So when I run the above, I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 4

If I try changing the call to this, as I have seen in other examples:

```
{ call GET_PEOPLE_IN_DEPT (?, :deptId) }
```

Then I get a different error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [{ call GET_PEOPLE_IN_DEPT(?, :deptId) }]

So my question is, what is the LEAST modification I need to get this to work? I've seen an example where they do this:

```
<sql-query name="callStockStoreProcedure">
<return alias="stock" class="com.mkyong.common.Stock"/>
<![CDATA[CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)]]>
</sql-query>
```

But that seems to be an older version of Hibernate and those tags are invalid. I guess I need to do something like that with the newer version, whatever that looks like...

Hibernate version they are using is 4.3

Answer (score 0):

According to [Hibernate 3.5 docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) (you are really using a legacy API here):

> For Oracle the following rules apply:
>
> ```
> A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set. This is done by
> ```
>
> using a SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or 10. In Oracle you need to
>   define a REF CURSOR type. See Oracle literature for further
>   information.

Try switching to the [new JPA API anyway and check out this tutorial](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa-part-2/).